# Output of multiple aggregate functions as rows instead of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am relativly new to SQL and aggregate functions.

I have this query, and I just want the max value for each month.

```
SELECT max(case when LogDate < '2016-06-01' and LogDate >= '2016-05-01' THEN value end),
       max(case when LogDate < '2016-07-01' and LogDate >= '2016-06-01' THEN value end),
       max(case when LogDate < '2016-08-01' and LogDate >= '2016-07-01' THEN value end) 
FROM RawData
```

It works, however the output is put in seperate column for each month, is there a way to make the output as rows in the same column instead?

I am using SQL server 2012

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very simple.

The "natural" output is in rows. The code in your question is to pivot it across columns.

```
SELECT YEAR(LogDate) AS Year,
       MONTH(LogDate) AS Month,
       MAX(value) AS MaxValue
FROM RawData
WHERE LogDate >= '2016-05-01' AND LogDate < '2016-08-01'
GROUP BY YEAR(LogDate), 
         MONTH(LogDate)
```

Comment: Didn't know about the month and year functions, thanks!